# Why do the sliders in Unity become non-interactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

I am having a problem with interactive sliders in my Unity project. I have one scene with all the player-related stuff: inventory/settings, loading screen, the game character itself, menu and some other things. It is layered on the top of the game map.

Firstly, sliders were working perfectly fine on different scenes and on canvas. I have only two sliders, and they are on the same scene but one is in the menu-game-object, which is turning off after entering the game, and another is on canvas, which always stays turned on.
Later, for some reason sliders in the menu-game-object became non-interactive as well as in the canvas. But on the one scene canvas-slider are interactive.

I have no idea how can I fix this problem. Maybe, someone here can help me?

Comment: Check the following:
1. In Inspector make sure Interactable is selected
2. Initial value of Value should be 0 or 100 depending on how u use it;
3. If you have a script that controls slider make sure it is attached properly
4. Check your script one more time
If it's still not working please provide more information

Answer (score 2):

The solution was easy. I just had to add the event system. It seems that sliders are just not working when there is no EventSystem

Comment: Where do you find this EventSystem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer: Slider is not interactable when there is an active animator component attached to it. Interaction works perfectly fine when the animator component is deactivated.

Comment: Can be added as comment